# How is fan/temperature control handled in virtual machines?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, fan, temperature

When you run a virtual machine, how are fans handled? Are fans real, nonexistent, or emulated? I would guess not all operating systems actually control the fan, and let underlying firmware do that. Is this often true? For example, if the guest OS tries to activate a fan, does the VM manager actually turn on a physical fan, or does it just pretend to? Does it not expose a fan, or pass temperature data, to the VM at all? In addition, would some guest operating systems run without a fan? Operating systems such as macOS know the hardware they're intended for, so would they assume they have a fan?

### EDIT

I know this is kind changes the setup, but since I didn't have a Ubuntu machine and VM handy, I used a mac and a Kali VM. The mac was able to read the fan (it said around 1700 RPM with little load, interesting) but `sensors-detect` found no sensors in the kali VM.

Comment: Would imagine fan control will be handle by bios and/or the host OS.  Quite a few PCs have bios control fans, some of the better PCs do let the OS have some control.  Guess OS should have no control, since it is the host that is really making the heat.  Mac OSs are quite picky about having all hardware work well when not on Mac hardware, some stuff just won't work.

Comment: I know the guest OS probably wouldn't have control, but it doesn't. So like what if I installed some tool to read fan speed? What would it see?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: That is good question.  Think it would depend if the computer had readable fan sensors.  Can always install and see, won't hurt anything.  Check if the host can read fans first, if host can't then VM won't either.

Comment: Fans are usually controlled by firmware unless you install software that instructs the firmware how to use them.

Comment: I would have already tried, but I probably don't know enough about hardware management to interpret the results. (If something says the speed is zero, is it, or does the fan not exist) etc. Will try though

Comment: If on Windows, speedfan is good, Ubuntu has psensors and a couple of others.  It really depends if your PC as fans that an OS program can read speed of.  All PCs have fans, but some can only be read and controlled by bios/firmware, not by OS.  A PC will have at least two vents, one intake and one exhaust, hand by exhaust will feel warm air coming out.

Comment: @Pixelated Fish  Was thinking that would be the case(your edit) since a VM is basically a fake PC, with limited ties to the main PC.  A VM expert might be able to do more.  Your fan speed seems to be okay, in range of low fan speed if fan/s are working/on.